# Mongoose Model.UpdateMany is not a function error on pre hook, this is working for similar schema and on the resolver

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This throws error   Station.UpdateMany is not a function but works when on resolver.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Station = require('./Station')

const customerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  stations: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Station'
  }]
 })

customerSchema.pre('save', async function() {
  await Station.updateMany( { _id:{ $in: this.stations } } ,{ $addToSet:{ customers: this._id } })
})    

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema)
```

Similar works on Station Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')
const Customer = require('./Customer')

const stationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customers: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Customer'
  }]
})

stationSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator)

stationSchema.pre('save',async function() {
  await Customer.updateMany({ _id:{ $in: this.customers } }, { $addToSet:{ stations: this._id } })
})

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Station',stationSchema)
```

No Idea why one works and not other?

Comment: Maybe you are defining the Middleware after Compiling Models? Calling pre() or post() after compiling a model does not work in Mongoose in general, as it say in the mongoose Middleware docs. see the example in [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining) for better understanding.

Comment: No, I don't think so, I removed both collection and reinitialized just to make sure this is not the case.

Comment: Then, it seems that your Station model have not been correctly exported/imported inside the file you're working on. Try checking that again.

Comment: Updated code to reflect the schema, everything looks ok to me and works when on resolver functions. I am going nuts.

Comment: The only thing I'm missing in your code is the "new" before "mongoose.Schema()" when you define your costumerSchema

Comment: Thanks, fixed that, but that doesn't change anything with my situation :D

Comment: Strange for me, but looking in docs I saw that adding the param {multi: true} solve this. Try with this code `await Station.updateMany( { _id:{ $in: this.stations } } ,{ $addToSet:{ costumers: this._id } }, {multi: true}) `

Comment: Nope, still not working

Comment: I'm getting out of ideas. One of the last things I can recomend you to use is the same code that I've typed above but in this case use `model.update()`. Even if that works I don't understand why `model.updateMany()`works in one and not in the other.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, this is because I am importing Costumer to Station so when Costumer is initalized inside station, station is not initalized thus the error. Verified it by removing Costumer import in station and everything works. Now the question is how can I make this work.

Comment: I can't do much more than recommend you to read this [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) about populate. I don't know all your project and what exactly are you aming for . (Maybe working on the same file could work but is a very ugly solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, the issue was because of cyclic dependency Station => Customer => Station. I solved it by importing the Model inside the pre hook instead of beginning on both Station and Customer. Hope this will help somebody.

```
   customerSchema.pre('save', async function() {
      const Station = require('./Station')
      await Station.updateMany( { _id:{ $in: this.stations } } ,{ $addToSet:{ customers: this._id } })
    })
```

Comment: hey @amrit. i ran into the same problem and this solution of yours made it work! im new to `mongodb` and `mongoose` and am still trying to make sense of stuff. though requiring within the hook works, it kinda feels "hackish"? have you thought of or implemented a better solution to this cyclic dependency problem? thanks!